# Disable chrome address autofill

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autofill

Is there a way to disable the autofill settings of chrome via html or javascript. [image]

I can disable them by switching it off on that screenshot above. But i am trying to look for a way to disable it by code. Though i am not sure if it really is possible to disable by code. I tried `autocomplete="off"`, `autocomplete="false"` and `autocomplete="nope"` on html but it did not work.

Comment: share the html code

Comment: Please don't prevent users from using useful features.

Comment: If you give them weird names and ids it might work. No guarantee though